# MongoDB Relationships

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Is there a way to say to Spring through code I have a table/collection in MongoDB for example Person. How would you say it has a 1 to many relationship with another table. Is this possible in MongoDB through Spring?

Comment: What would you do with such a relationship?

Comment: I wanted to know if this is possible. As MongoDB is NoSQL database. For example an Employee has many cars. Is this actually possible to do?

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of NoSQL was not having things like relationships (foreign keys)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for MongoDB to have 'relationships' with other databases and collections, these are called Manual References and DBRefs.  Look in the documentation [for database references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/).  You should however be wary using these, as they will almost always perform poorly in comparison to using a single collection.  Either your application or the driver is going to need to query twice for the data - once in the original collection and once in the other collection to resolve the reference.

It is a common mistake for those coming from a relational model to try and emulate joins in MongoDB with the use of DBRefs.  In the example you give, a one-to-many relationship is likely better modelled in a single collection with embedding, like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "Name" : "Bob",
    "Cars" : {
        "CarName1" : "FirstCar",
        "CarName2" : "SecondCar"
    }
}
```

You can check out the docs on [Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) for more information

Answer (score 2):

MongoDb doesn't provide any support for relationship between multiple collections. It is different from the sql approach of databases. No-sql supports logical relationship which is maintained by the schema design itself. The basic goal of it is to reduce dependency on parts of documents and speedup the process. For demo example you could visit [mongodb-useful-basics](http://www.tinytute.com/mongodb-useful-basics/)